# GEE: Compute Map of Correlation with reduceNeighborhood

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, scale, reducers, correlation

I want to compute the correlation between NDVI and Preciptation by using reduceNeighborhood() to calculate the correlation on a local scale. The original resolution of the NDVI Layer was 500m, the resolution of the Precipitation Layer was 11132m. I resampled and reprojected both, so they should have the same resolution, even if there are larger areas with the same precipitation value.

However, I have a strange issue:
The computation doesn't produce a complete map but a grid of stripes. These stripes lay exactly on the boundaries of different precipitation values. If I test the calculation with twice the same NDVI layer, the grid lines lay also around the areas with the same NDVI value so I think it's not a problem with projection or resolution.

It seems that the problem is related to the scale, because zooming out increases the width of the stripes. When I zoom out completely, the map looks like the map I want to have.
I also tried exporting the computed map with a scale of 500. When I import this map, the width of the stripes remainds fixed to 8 pixels but there are still large gaps.

Is there any way to solve this problem? I don't really know where I need to change something.

Here is my code:

```js
var ndvi = ee.Image("MODIS/061/MOD13A1/2021_07_28").select('NDVI').clip(geometry)
var prec = ee.Image("NASA/GPM_L3/IMERG_MONTHLY_V06/20210701000000").select('precipitation').multiply(744).clip(geometry)

var xVar = prec
var yVar = ndvi

var ndviPrecCombined = xVar.addBands(yVar).rename(['Prec', 'NDVI']);
print('ndviPrecCombined', ndviPrecCombined)

var pearsonCorrMap = ndviPrecCombined.reduceNeighborhood(
  ee.Reducer.pearsonsCorrelation(),
  ee.Kernel.square(4.5))
```

For looking at the reimported layer, [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/5d81657b9a864402f999dbe8992e4060) is my code in GEE.